# Is MySQL performant with select ... in (ID1,ID2,ID3,...ID100)?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Will this kind of query bring performance issue?

Comment: Please rewrite this question in English.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an index on whatever field you are doing the `IN` on, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* query will cause performance issues (to some degree, technically). The question is not whether it will cause performance issues, the question is whether it's necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Versus what? As long as your WHERE clause values are indexed appropriately, you should be fine (in general).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes yes, but sometimes this syntax is also necessary or better than any alternative you might have to achieve the same result set. In order to fully say that in your case the performance will be worse than it would be with a differently written query, we would need to know your exact query and database schema.